# Adding a sparse vector to a dense vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

Suppose I have a high dimensional vector v which is dense and another high dimensional vector x which is sparse and I want to do an operation which looks like

v = v + x

Ideally since one needs to update only a few entries in v this operation should be fast but it is still taking a good amount of time even when I have declared x to be sparse. I have tried with v being in full as well as v being in sparse form and both are fairly slow.

I have also tried to extract the indices from the sparse vector x by calling a find and then updating the original vector in a for loop. This is faster than the above operations, but is there a way to achieve the same with much less code.

Thanks

Comment: This question might also be of use: [Fast way to set many values of sparse matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443031/fast-way-to-set-many-values-of-sparse-matrix/32443174)

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-operations.html#f6-13064) (**emphasis** mine):

> Binary operators yield sparse results if both operands are sparse, and full results if both are full. For mixed operands, the result is full unless the operation preserves sparsity. **If S is sparse and F is full, then S+F, S*F, and F\S are full, while S.*F and S&F are sparse.** In some cases, the result might be sparse even though the matrix has few zero elements.

Therefore, if you wish to keep `x` sparse, I think using logical indexing to update `v` with the nonzero values of `x` is best.  Here is a sample function that shows either logical indexing or explicitly `full`-ing `x` is best (at least on my R2015a install):

```
function [] = blur()

    n = 5E6;
    v = rand(n,1);
    x = sprand(n,1,0.001);
    xf = full(x);
    vs = sparse(v);

    disp(['Full-Sparse:   ',num2str(timeit(@() v + x)      ,'%9.5f')]);
    disp(['Full-Full:     ',num2str(timeit(@() v + xf)     ,'%9.5f')]);
    disp(['Sparse-Sparse: ',num2str(timeit(@() vs + x)     ,'%9.5f')]);
    disp(['Logical Index: ',num2str(timeit(@() update(v,x)),'%9.5f')]);

end

function [] = update(v,x)

    mask = x ~= 0;
    v(mask) = v(mask) + x(mask);

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is reasonably fast. In my experiments a factor faster than the for loop approach and with less code.

Comment: Why is Full-Sparse slower than Full-Full? My question related to this matter is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931838/matlab-why-is-full-sparse-matrix-addition-slower-than-full-full-matrix-addition

Comment: @rnoodle Full-Sparse requires a promotion of the sparse to full or a special routine to handle the interaction. In either case, the associate overhead maybe noticably greater than the computation of a strictly Full-Full operation that has had its algorithms studied and optimized to death.

Comment: @TroyHaskin If the number of sparse elements in the full/sparse addition is relatively small to the full matrix, then surely just adding those elements in-place to the full matrix would be efficient - rather than having to promote the sparse matrix?